# При открытии сайта сразу отображается нижняя секция

Tags: html, css

Собственно делал лендиг, сделал форму отправки сообщений, теперь при входе на сайт окно браузера сразу же перемещается к ней. Как это исправить? Нужно чтобы сайт открывался в обычном порядке :( Надеюсь на помощь. Сам сайт http://apple36.ru/lp/

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сами в коде в `main.js` делаете фокус на `textarea`

```
$('#free_quest').focus();
```

по этому браузер скролит вас к форме